# SQL Server Compact Edition - Any way to compile the code in AnyCPU?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, 64-bit, sql-server-ce

Either v3.5 or v4.0...it seems that there is either an x86 version or x64 version - is there a way to compile my c# code with the AnyCPU flag?  I'd hate to have to peg my app to a certain architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a way. I assume you want to do a "private deployment" for SQL CE.

In which case, you put x86 versions of the SQL CE assemblies into a subfolder of your deployment named `x86`. You put the x64 assemblies into a subfolder of your deployment named `AMD64`.

I did this a while ago, but I believe the key links were [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLCEPrivateInstallation.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2007/07/11/sql-server-compact-and-64bit-support.aspx). I also think there was a key bit of a doco in the SQL CE Books Online on how to extract the x64 assemblies if you're only using an x86 development machine.

Answer (score 0):

The AnyCPU flag should work, you will have to install the appropriate version of sqlce for your platform, the application will automatically run in that configuration.